# Reading a .txt file in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

So im trying to write a program in C++ that takes input line by line from a text file and give it as and output but im running into errors that I cant find very good answers to. Thanks in advance for the help

Code is:

```
    1 #include "stdafx.h"
    2 #include <iostream>
    3 #include <fstream>
    4 #include <string>
    5 using namespace std;
    6 int main()
    7 {
    8    string line;
    9    ifstream file("INPUT.txt");
   10    if (file.is_open())
   11    {
   12             while(getline(file,line)
   13              {
   14                     cout << line << '\n'
   15              }
   16              file.close();
   17
   18     }
   19      else
   20       { 
   21          cout << "file is not open" << '\n';
   22       }
   23     
   24      return 0;
   25  }
```

The errors from the compiler read:

line(15): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

and

line(16): error C2146: syntax error: missing ')' before identifier 'file'

Comment: missing a semicolon end of line 14

Comment: ps useful error messages have never been a big part of c++

Comment: Especially with the VS compiler. gcc does quite a bit better job, but does suffer from the wall-to-wall dump of template, trait and class information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line 12 is missing a closing parentheses, should be:
`while(getline(file,line))`

line 14 is missing a semicolon, should be:
`cout << line << '\n';`

Final:

```
~/tmp/junk > cat a.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  string line;
  ifstream file("INPUT.txt");
  if (file.is_open())
  {
    while(getline(file,line))
    {
      cout << line << '\n';
    }
    file.close();
  }
  else
  { 
    cout << "file is not open" << '\n';
  }
  return 0;
}
```